# php array shift keys multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this.

```
$array = array ( '18' => array (  '1' =>'', '14' =>''),
                 '23' => array ( '24' =>''), 
                 '24' => array ( '25' =>'', '26' =>''),
                 '26' => array ( '27' =>'', '28' =>''), 
                 '30' => array ( '23' =>'', '31' =>'')
                );
```

I wanna this array to rearrange like this.

```
 Array 
(
[18] => Array
    (
    [1] =>
    [14] =>
    )
[30] => Array
    (
    [23] => Array
       ( 
        [24] => Array
           ( 
            [25] =>
            [26] => Array
               ( 
                [27] =>
                [28] =>
               )
           )
      )
   )
)
```

I appreciate someone's help.

Comment: isn't this already arranged ?

Comment: where is the second array?? you have written "I wanna this array to rearrange like this" which will be for 2 arrays. 1st array is input array & second array is rearranged array as output.

Comment: Only this much content or very lot of content? If some much mean you can arrange Manually. Otherwise it's need some codes. What about you?

Answer (score 0):

This script is too close but after 24 index have some issues

```
<?php 

class arrayTest
{
    //create the array
    public $array = array ( '18' => array ( '1' => '', '14' => ''),
        '23' => array ( '24' =>''),
        '24' => array ( '25' =>'', '26' =>''),
        '26' => array ( '27' =>'', '28' =>''),
        '30' => array ('23'=>'','31'=>'')
        );

    public $data = array();

    public function index()
    {
        //data array
        $data =array();

        //process each key of the array
        foreach($this->array as $key=>$val)
        {
            //check the key value
            if($key==18 || $key==30)
            {
                //process the child array
                foreach($val as $key1=>$val1)
                {
                    //bind the expectation
                    $data[$key][$key1] =isset($this->array[$key1])?$this->get_array($key1):'';
                }
            }

        }

        //output
        print_r($data);
    }


    //function process the each array
    function get_array($index)
    {       
        //process the each array
        foreach($this->array[$index] as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(isset($this->array[$key]) && is_array($this->array[$key]))
            {
                foreach($this->array[$key] as $key1=>$value1)
                {
                    //
                    $this->data[$key] = isset($this->array[$key1])?$this->get_array($key1):'';
                }

            }else{

                $this->data[$key] = '';
            }
        }

        return $this->data;
    }


}


    $obj = new arrayTest();

    $obj->index();
```

Comment: @Heman Yes, you are right, my answer is equally inadequate. You will have to use some kind of recursion to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks guys. but the out put i'm getting is different to what I expect. it should be like this                                                 Array 
(
[18] => Array
    (
    [1] =>
    [14] =>
    )
[30] => Array
    (
    [23] => Array
       ( 
        [24] => Array
           ( 
            [25] =>
            [26] => Array
               ( 
                [27] =>
                [28] =>
               )
           )
      )
   )
)

Comment: @cars10: Thanks for your help. any other suggestions to get the expected result? I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Sundar: Thanks for your time man. Any suggestions to get the right output?

Comment: This is good for small size array if array is too big then you goes into memory_exceed error try to add reference into the array and clear the memory frequently

Answer (score 0):

**2. Edit:**

I modified my iterative solution such that the total length of the resulting array in text-format is checked. If the length has not changed, the iteration will exit.

(**Modified**) Sample data:

```
$a=array('18'=> array (  '1' =>'', '14' =>''),
                '20' => array ( '32' =>''),
                '23' => array ( '24' =>''), 
                '24' => array ( '25' =>'', '26' =>''),
                '26' => array ( '27' =>'', '28' =>''),
                '29' => array ( '33' =>''), 
                '30' => array ( '23' =>'', '31' =>''),
                '32' => array ( '30' =>''),
                '33' => array ( '32' =>'')
               );
```

Code:

```
function plough(&$a){ // ploughs throught the array once from top to bottom ...
 foreach ($a as $ak => &$av){
  foreach($av as $k => &$v) {
   if(isset($a[$k])) $v=$a[$k];
  }
 }
 return strlen(print_r($a,1)); // returns string-length of print_r-output
}

// iterate until there is no change in string-length any more ...
for ($al1=1+$al0=0 ;$al0<$al1; $al1=plough($a)) $al0=$al1;
print_r($a);
```

By placing the `&` before the variable names in the `foreach` loops you are working with the references to these vaiables and not with copied values. Applying the routine on my (modified) example results in the following

output:

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [1] => 
            [14] => 
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [32] => Array
                (
                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [23] => Array
                                (
                                    [24] => Array
                                        (
                                            [25] => 
                                            [26] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [27] => 
                                                    [28] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [31] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [24] => Array
                (
                    [25] => 
                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [27] => 
                            [28] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [25] => 
            [26] => Array
                (
                    [27] => 
                    [28] => 
                )

        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [33] => Array
                (
                    [32] => Array
                        (
                            [30] => Array
                                (
                                    [23] => Array
                                        (
                                            [24] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [25] => 
                                                    [26] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [27] => 
                                                            [28] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [31] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [23] => Array
                (
                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [25] => 
                            [26] => Array
                                (
                                    [27] => 
                                    [28] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [31] => 
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [30] => Array
                (
                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [24] => Array
                                (
                                    [25] => 
                                    [26] => Array
                                        (
                                            [27] => 
                                            [28] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [31] => 
                )

        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [32] => Array
                (
                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [23] => Array
                                (
                                    [24] => Array
                                        (
                                            [25] => 
                                            [26] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [27] => 
                                                    [28] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [31] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for getting back. The prob is rec level is not consistent. These key values are company Ids. In this example all the sub companies are listed under head company. In some cases sub companies have many subchild companies and it keeps going like that. Not sure what to do :(

Comment: Thanks mate. it works fine. Really appreciate your support & help. Great work!